# Horn of Valere - why are people still searching?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I'm currently on book 6 of the Wheel of Time books. At this point, people all over the world are still actively searching for the Horn of Valere, even though *we* know it has already been blown by Mat at the battle of Falme, and I believe the horn itself is in Tar Valon.

So, since word spread of the battle of Falme, why hasn't word spread that the Horn was blown and these ancient heroes came out to fight? I cant believe that no one noticed them, and I can't figure out why people are still searching for it. Shouldn't it be common knowledge in that world by now?

Comment: as you read the books you see how bad the news travels, they have all these rumors about the horn but at the same time you have rummors of a guy fighting in the sky, of people on flying beasts, armies coming from across the ocean, Yet there's almost no reliable sources. even when the briar?(i think) from the whitecloaks talsk to the commander of the white cloaks he doesn't believe the first hand witness about half of the things he saw, everyone else is getting far less reliable story. you can tell "normal" people are quite skeptical of these stories.

Comment: Throughout the books we see examples of what we know to be real news reaching someone's ears in the form of rumours indistinguishable from many other rumours. When this real news is utterly ridiculous (dead heroes coming back to fight? invaders from across the Aryth Ocean?), it's likely to be dismissed as completely wild rumour.

Comment: Additionally, Hunters for the Horn seem to be hailed as heroes in allot of places they travel. Even a hunter that was pretty sure the horn was found, might still play the role just for the attention they receive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's not really that many people to spread the rumours.

The Battle at Falme had three actors:

1. The Whitecloaks -- who were all but destroyed. Their leader had set an officer to observe, but he became obsessed with pursuing Perrin rather than spreading the truth of events.
2. The Seanchan -- who aren't the most talkative lot when around normal people. They also retreated across the seas to regroup.
3. The Army of Shienar -- recently having lost their commander -- who are loyal to the new Dragon (mostly) but then come under the thrall of the Prophet.

None of these groups are particularly trustworthy for a lot of the series. For a long time, people don't believe the Seanchan exist. People ignore the Whitecloaks wherever they can. And the Shienarans go hide in some hills very shortly after the battle.

There are also other events going on -- most interestingly the battle between Rand and Ishamael in the sky above the battle. This scene was more easily observable for people not directly involved in the battle, and so rumours of it spread more quickly.

No one *announces* that the Horn was used. People don't make the connection between a legend no one really believes in and a battle people think is just propaganda for another false Dragon. By the time Rand is more accepted, there's other things to talk about and the Horn is safely locked away in Tar Valon.

Comment: I *think* also that there's probably only a few months between The Great Hunt and the Lord of Chaos in the timeline. The whole series occurs over only three or four years IIRC.